# Creating a date range picker using two select boxes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, model

I'd like to setup a model that would allow a date range depicting a timeframe of activity-inactivity. So for example you have an `employee` model and would be able to set his/her duration of employment from a start date to an end date. Essentially there would be two select boxes that would allow you to do this. If the employee is still employed there would be an option in the second box labeled "current".

I've looked around for an existing answer to this problem and it seems most direct you towards using either `date_select` or `select_year` to create a range within **one** select box. I'm looking to do something of the sort using two select boxes (start / end || current) and saving the two values to the database. Now for the second select box I wanted to have it default to the current year and be called "Current", indicating there is no end date yet.

Looking through the Rails API there's an option for a `prompt` but I'm not exactly sure how to have that prompt represent a physical value and reside at the top of the list. For something as simple as this I was leaning towards not using an extensive jQuery datepicker plugin to reduce the unnecessary overhead. I'm open to using SimpleForm but haven't found a way to do this through that gem.

**What I have now:**

```
<% form_for @product do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :employed %>
  <%= select_year(Date.today, start_year: 2000, end_year: 2012) %>
  <%= select_year(Date.today, :start_year => Date.today.year, :end_year => 8.years.from_now.year) %>
<% end %>
```

I'm wondering if creating two attributes to the employee model specifying these date (stardate + enddate) would work or could you possibly do this in one fell swoop (I'm assuming the latter would be cleaner)?

Answer (score -1):

I would consider creating a separate table to store these values, call it `EmploymentPeriod`.  An `Employee` then `has_many` `EmploymentPeriods`, which could be useful to keep track of... *(maybe an employee is a student, and works one summer, and then returns the following, for example)*.

`EmploymentPeriod` could keep track of things like `start_date`, `end_date`, and even something like `salary`, for that particular period *(maybe the student gets a raise the following summer...)*.

To recap:

```
    Employee has_many :employment_periods
    EmploymentPeriod belongs_to :employee   # e.g. it has an employee_id foreign key
```

This is how I would tackle it!  Good luck.

Comment: If my answer was unhelpful, a comment indicating **why** would be more constructive than a simple down-vote. Thanks!